# MYSQL insert string from html's text area with semi-colon...advise?

Tags: php, mysql, html, textarea

This is in regards to PHP, Mysql and Html's textarea.

I want to dump a user's input from html's textarea into my mysql database. The situation is that if the user has semi-colons within the text itself, mysql will reject the insert command for obvious reasons. What I want to know is that are there any ways to force mysql to take in a user's input regardless of its syntax?

Much appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape any SQL special characters, such as semi-colon. [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) might be useful.

Don't forget to escape user input if you send it back to a browser, otherwise you will be vulnerable to XSS (cross-site scripting) attacks. Of course, this time you'll need to escape HTML special characters, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Any text fields should be escaped using the php function "mysql_real_escape_string" before being inserted into MySQL:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but to add to what he said, you can use `strip_tags()` to sanitize output to avoid XSS.